# Is there a way to split a DF using column name comparison?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

I am extremely new to Python. I've created a DataFrame using a csv file. My file is a complex nested json file having header values at the lowest granular level.
[Example] `df.columns = [ID1, fullID2, total.count, total.value, seedValue.id, seedValue.value1, seedValue.value2, seedValue.largeFile.id, seedValue.largeFile.value1, seedValue.largeFile.value2......]`

Requirement: I have to create multiple smaller csvs using each of the columns that are granular and ID1, fullID2.
My approach that I figured is: save the smaller slices by splitting on the header value.
Problem 1: Not able to split the value correctly or traverse to the first location for comparison.
[Example]
I'm using `df.columns.str.split('.').tolist()`. Suppose I get the below listed value, I want to compare seedValue of id with seedValue of value1 and pull out this entire part as a new df.
`{['seedValue','id'],['seedValue'.'value1'], ['seedValue'.'value2']}`
Problem 2: Adding ID1 and fullID2 to this new df.

Any help or direction to achieve this would be super helpful !
[Final output]

```
df.columns = [ID1, fullID2, total.count, total.value, seedValue.id, seedValue.value1, seedValue.value2, seedValue.largeFile.id, seedValue.largeFile.value1, seedValue.largeFile.value2......]
post-processing the file -
seedValue.columns = ID1,fullID2,id,value1,value2
total.columns = ID1,fullID2,count,value
seedValue.largeFile.columns = ID1,fullID2,id,value1,value2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not possess your complex data to provide a more particular solution. I was able to reproduce a similar case with a *.csv* sample data, which will exemplify how to achieve what you aim with your data.

In order to save in each **ID** in a different file, we need to loop through the ID's. Also, assuming there might be more duplicate ID's, the script will save each group of ID's into a *.csv* file. Below is the script, already with sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

my_dict = { 'ids' : [11,11,33,55,55],
                   'info' : ["comment_1","comment_2", "comment_3", "comment_4", "comment_5"],
                   'other_column': ["something", "something", "something", "", "something"]}

#Creating a dataframe from the .csv file
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
#sorting the value
df = df.sort_values('ids')
#g=df.groupby('ids')
df

#looping through each group of ids and saving them into a file
for id,g in df.groupby('ids'):
    g.to_csv('id_{}.csv'.format(id),index=False)#, header=True, index_label=False)
```

And the output,

```
id_11.csv
id_33.csv
id_55.csv
```

For instance, within *`id_11.csv`*:

```
ids info      other_column
11  comment_1 something
11  comment_2 something
```

Notice that, we use the field ***ids*** in the name of each file. Moreover, `index=False` which means that a new column with indexes for each line of data won't be created.

*ADDITIONAL INFO: I have used the Notebook in AI Platform within GCP to execute and test the code.*

Comment: Thanks for your input, its helpful for automation for generating the csv files. My current issue is that I need to open any inner columns with type dictionary and store them into separate csvs. I'm guessing I'd have to generate some IDs that is going to link these files. For example:
 ``` df5 = pd.DataFrame(df['somecol'].tolist())
df5.columns
{A,B,C,{d,e,f,g,h,{i,j,k},l},M,N}
```
Now I should extract all the inner dictionaries to new CSV files. To link these together, I was thinking in the lines of:
```
{A,B,C,ID,M,N}
{ID,d,e,f,g,h,id,l}
{id,i,j,k}
```
All inputs are welcome. Thanks

Comment: @ZeLearner, would you mind sharing a piece of your data so I can test it in my envirment?

Comment: I have gone by simple for looping over the entire dataframe and picking up the required columns out. Thanks for your help extended.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to the more widely known `pd.read_csv`, pandas offers more granular json support through [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), which allows you to specify how to unnest the data, which meta-data to use, etc.

Apart from this, reading nested fields from a csv into a two-dimensional dataframe might not be the ideal solution here, and having nested objects inside a dataframe can often be tricky to work with.

Try to read the file as a pure dictionary or list of dictionaries. You can then loop through the keys and create a custom logic to check how many more levels you want to go down, how to return the values and so on. Once you are on a lower level and prefer to have this inside of a dataframe, create a new temporary dataframe, then append these parts together inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. I used the function to normalize part of my file and then could work out working on the rest.